# TabView suddenly missing from UWP

Tags: uwp, tabs

Was trying to implement a TabView in my UWP project yesterday but it doesn't show up in the ToolBox and if I add it via code it says

> TabView is not supported in a Windows Universal Project.

Though the documentation on the website is fairly recent and clear: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tab-view

I put the UWP requirement on latest Windows 10 build. Running Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise.

More information or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.tabview?view=winui-2.3) of TabView, you can see that the TabView is under the **Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls** namespace and applies to WinUI. So you need to install **Microsoft.UI.Xaml** nuget package and add the Windows UI (WinUI) Theme Resources to your App.xaml resources. Then add the namespace in xaml to use it.

App.xaml:

```
<Application ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
    ......
    xmlns:control="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls">

    <Grid>
        <control:TabView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            ......
        </control:TabView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: When you install the Microsoft.UI.Xaml nuget package, you will notice that there is a file `readme.txt` that appears next to the `NuGet - Solution` in the left pane of `VS2019`. That file tells what needs to be added to the `App.xaml` file.

Answer (score 3):

It's confusing, but there are *(at least)* two TabViews you can use in UWP applications:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.tabview

```
xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
...
<muxc:TabView>
```

and from the windows community toolkit

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.tabview

```
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
...
<controls:TabView >
```

They look different. The toolkit version is flatter, and have slightly different naming and hierarchy for some properties.

If you're not careful about which documentation your reading from, you can end up with code that is an invalid mishmash of the properties hierarchy from both classes.

Answer (score 0):

`TabView` is suddenly missing on first as default because microsoft didn't create any `TabView` project. The `TabView` released on `WinUI 2.2`. Then you need to add `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls` on Application, XMAL as `muxc` and C# as `muxc`. Make sure your `WinUI` project 2.2.
Example on Application XAML :-

```
<Application ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and XMAL :-

```
<Page ... xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" ...>

    <Grid>
         <muxc:TabView/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

and C# :-

```
using muxc = Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namspace {Your_Project}
{
    public sealed partical class {Your_Page} : Page
    {
         ...

         public {Your_Page}
         {
              this.InitializeComponent();
         }

         ...
    }
}
```

Click [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/tab-view) for more details or information